# Our priority is to have

Tags: word-usage

> Our priority is to have you turn over the money to the people.

Now I heard that somewhere what does it mean please explain.

Comment: If you *heard* it, you need to work on your grasp of *spoken* English (unless your writing one-word ***turnover*** was just a typo). The pronunciation of the verb *(to **turn over** the page)* and noun *(bake an apple **turnover**)* forms are very different. In the cited context, ***hand over*** would probably be at least as likely (or maybe ***return***, if that's more accurate).

Comment: Maybe it's just my opinion, but I feel that when you *turn* something over to someone else, it's more likely to be something they don't want and/or weren't expecting (such as some responsibility that you're ducking out of). But if you *hand* it over, it's more likely to be something they asked for (perhaps repeatedly, and you've finally yielded). Thus the mugger says *Hand over the money!*, not *Turn over the money!*

Comment: Sorry they weren't talking about money, they were talking about the iron man suit do you want me to paste the clip link here

Comment: I've found the text [here](http://theamericanculture.org/iron-man-2-trailer-a-free-market-solution-to-world-peace/), where it's correctly transcribed (***turn over*** is two words, effectively a phrasal verb roughly equivalent to ***hand over***). If you have a link to Senator Stern actually *speaking* those words, I'm sure you'll agree it's two separate words. But yes please - edit your text to include a link. I don't see why you changed the thing demanded from *the Iron Man weapon* to *the money* anyway, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

It means that their priority is to make sure that he gives away his money to the people.

Comment: Oh now I understand, actually I heard it in iron man 2 movie trailer.